# Efficiently filtering nested list of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a nested list of dictionary like follows:

```
list_of_dict = [
       {
         "key": "key1",
         "data": [
             {
               "u_key": "u_key_1",
               "value": "value_1"
             },
             {
               "u_key": "u_key_2",
               "value": "value_2"
             }
         ]
       },

       {
         "key": "key2",
         "data": [
             {
                "u_key": "u_key_1",
                "value": "value_3"
             },
             {
               "u_key": "u_key_2",
               "value": "value_4"
             }
         ]
       }
    ]
```

As you can see `list_of_dict` is a list of dict and inside that, `data` is also a list of dict. Assume that all the objects inside `list_of_dict` and `data` has similar structure and all the keys are always present.

In the next step I convert `list_of_dict` to `list_of_tuples`, where first element of tuple is `key` followed by all the values against `value` key inside `data`

```
list_of_tuples = [
          ('key1', 'value_1'), 
          ('key1', 'value_2'),
          ('key2', 'value_3'), 
          ('key2','value_4')
]
```

The final step is comparison with a list(`comparison_list`). List contains `string` values. The values inside the list CAN be from the `value` key inside data. I need to check if any value inside `comparison_list` is inside `list_of_tuples` and fetch the key(first item of tuple) of that value.

```
comparison_list = ['value_1', 'value_2']
```

My expected output is:

```
out = ['key1', 'key1']
```

My solution is follows:

```
  >>> list_of_tuples = [(c.get('key'),x.get('value')) 
               for c in list_of_dict for x in c.get('data')]

  >>> for t in list_of_tuple:
          if t[1] in comparison_list:
              print("Found: {}".format(t[0]))
```

So summary of problem is that I have list of values(`comparison_list`) which I need to find inside `data` array.

The dataset that I am operating on is quite huge(>100M). I am looking to speed up my solution and also make it more compact and readable.
Can I somehow skip the step where I create `list_of_tuples` and do the comparison directly?

Comment: Somehow your example does not fit. Did you mean `(c.get('key'),x.get('value')`? Anyway, if you want to speed that up, it's probably a good stark making `comparison_list` a `set`.

Comment: @tobias_k yes i have edited the question. I will give it a try with set thanks :)

Comment: comparison_list = ['value_1', 'value_2'] is your expected output?

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul I have added my expected output

Comment: Also, could it be that there are a few too many `{...}` in your `list_of_dict`? It seems to be a `set` containing a single `list` (which is not possible in Python), same for the `data` entries, which are sets with each one dict (again, not possible).

Comment: @tobias_k sorry I didn't get you.

Comment: @GarbageCollector as you said , In the next step I convert list_of_dict to list_of_tuples , How you are iterating over list_of_dict because its unhashable type  'dict'  ?

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul sorry about that I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few simple optimization you can try:

- make `comparison_list` a `set` so the lookup is O(1) instead of O(n)
- make `list_of_tuples` a generator, so you don't have to materialize all the entries at once
- you can also integrate the condition into the generator itself

Example:

```
comparison_set = set(['value_1', 'value_2'])
tuples_generator = ((c['key'], x['value']) 
                    for c in list_of_dict for x in c['data']
                    if x['value'] in comparison_set)
print(*tuples_generator)
# ('key1', 'value_1') ('key1', 'value_2')
```

Of course, you can also keep the comparison separate from the generator:

```
tuples_generator = ((c['key'], x['value']) 
                    for c in list_of_dict for x in c['data'])
for k, v in tuples_generator:
    if v in comparison_set:
        print(k, v)
```

Or you could instead create a `dict` mapping values from `comparison_set` to keys from `list_of_dicts`. This will make finding the key to a particular value faster, but note that you can then only keep one key to each value.

```
values_dict = {x['value']: c['key'] 
               for c in list_of_dict for x in c['data']
               if x['value'] in comparison_set}
print(values_dict)
# {'value_2': 'key1', 'value_1': 'key1'}
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid tuple generator step and compare directly with `list_of_dict`?

Comment: @GarbageCollector What do you mean? What would be the expected result of that? The `tuple_generator` should not do much harm, it's basically just a lazily-evaluated instruction for an iterator.

Comment: Yes I understand that generator would be a really good idea to use it. However if you see the solution i posted at the end of question, there are two steps. Generate list of tuples and file key for matching item from `comparison_list`. I would like to skip the tuple generation and do the comparison directly.

Comment: @GarbageCollector Still not sure what you mean. Of course, you can keep it as two steps (see edit), but then _in particular_ I would suggest using a generator, as many items of the list will likely be throws away anyway. And of course you can also "skip the generator" and use a nested `for` loop instead... but IMHO the generator is cleaner and more reusable.

Answer (score 1):

In last step you can use filter  something like this instead of iterating over that:

```
comparison_list = ['value_1', 'value_2']

print(list(filter(lambda x:x[1] in comparison_list,list_of_tuples)))
```

output:

```
[('key1', 'value_1'), ('key1', 'value_2')]
```

Comment: When you say "without loops" this sounds as if this would not need to loop, but it still does, inside `list` and  `map`. The list comprehension `[[(x.get('key'),g.get('value')) for g in x.get('data')] for x in list_of_dict]` is not only easier to parse (for a human) but also almost twice as fast.

Comment: @tobias_k i know but do you know built-in and local scope ? built-in are written in 'c' language and when you use for loop its local scope loop , search about it .

Comment: I guess I do; what about it? You say "builtins are implemented in C", so `%timeit` is lying to me when it says that the list comprehension is faster? Also, instead of "google it", why not put the arguments directly into your answer?

Comment: Also note that you are creating a _nested_ list. Your own `filter` line will not work with that, but only with OP's original _flat_ `list_of_tuples`.

Comment: @tobias_k yes , i agree genex is faster than lambda.